# Округление до 2 знаков после запятой Haskell

Tags: haskell

Недавно начал пробовать Haskell на примере маленьких задачек - хеллоуворлдов. Сама задача состоит в том, что нужно посчитать некоторое выражение при разных `x` - ничего сложного. Но для красоты решил округлить ответ до 2 знаков после запятой и тут столкнулся со сложностями. Так как стандартной реализации такого округления не нашел, *завелосипедил* свою:

```
main :: IO ()        
main = do 
           let x = 1.7
               in putStrLn $ show $ roundTo2 ((x + 1) ^ 2 + 3 * (x + 1))

roundTo2 :: Num a => a -> Float
roundTo2 x = truncate (x * 100) / 100
```

Ругань компилятора:

```
Could not deduce (RealFrac a) arising from a use of \`truncate'
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the type signature for roundTo2 :: Num a => a -> Float
      at prog.hs:6:13-31
    Possible fix:
      add (RealFrac a) to the context of
        the type signature for roundTo2 :: Num a => a -> Float
    In the first argument of \`(/)', namely \`truncate (x * 100)'
    In the expression: truncate (x * 100) / 100
    In an equation for `roundTo2':
        roundTo2 x = truncate (x * 100) / 100
```

Понимаю что проблема где-то в типах, но не понимаю, как эту проблему решить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию printf из модуля Text.Printf.

```
import Text.Printf

main :: IO ()        
main = do 
    let x = 1.7
    printf "%.2f\n" ((x + 1) ^ 2 + 3 * (x + 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Поборол ошибку следующим образом:

```
main :: IO ()        
main = do 
           let x = 1.7
               f = (x + 1) ^ 2 + 3 * (x + 1)
               in print $ roundTo2 f

roundTo2 :: (RealFrac a) => a -> a
roundTo2 x = fromIntegral f / 100
                 where f = round (x * 100)
```

Проблема оказалась в функции деления `(/)` а не `truncate`, как я предполагал(Кстати в итоговом решении заменил на `round` как более подходящую). 
Суть проблемы в том, что деление в Haskell определено для дробных аргументов, принадлежащих классу типов `Fractional`:

```
:t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

Но `truncate`(и `round`) возвращают значение целочисленного типа `Integral`:

```
:t round
round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

Для решения задачи я воспользовался функцией `fromIntegral`, которая приводит значение целочисленного типа к значению произвольного числового типа `Num`, подклассом которого является класс `Fractional`:

```
:t fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, можно воспользоваться советом из текста об ошибке: добавить класс (RealFrac a) в определение типа функции. (Num a) при этом можно убрать: RealFrac  включает в себя Num.

Во-вторых, можно воспользоваться ghci и подсмотреть тип функции:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> let roundTo2 x = truncate (x * 100) / 100
Prelude> :t roundTo2
roundTo2 :: (Fractional a, Integral a, RealFrac a1) => a1 -> a
```

Comment: Проблема оказалась в типах функций деления и округления